# When defining tangent spaces, given $\gamma:(-1,1)\to M$ and $\varphi:U\to\mathbb R^n,U\subseteq M$, why is $\varphi\circ\gamma:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, tangent-spaces

So I was reading an article on Wikipedia [on tangent spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) but I have a question.

So the definition is as follows,

> Suppose that  $M$ is a $C^{k}$ differentiable manifold (with smoothness $k\ge 1$ and that  $x \in M$. Pick a coordinate chart $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb {R} ^{n}$, where ${\displaystyle U}$ is an open subset of ${\displaystyle M}$ containing ${\displaystyle x}$. Suppose further that two curves ${\displaystyle \gamma _{1},\gamma _{2}:(-1,1)\to M}$ with ${\displaystyle {\gamma _{1}}(0)=x={\gamma _{2}}(0)}$ are given such that both ${\displaystyle \varphi \circ \gamma _{1},\varphi \circ \gamma _{2}:(-1,1)\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$ are differentiable

My question is how is  **${\displaystyle \varphi \circ \gamma _{1},\varphi \circ \gamma _{2}:(-1,1)\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$**?

How does this composition of $\varphi$ and $\gamma $ become from $(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is marginally imprecise as written. For the composition to make sense, we have to have $\gamma_1((-1,1)),\gamma_2((-1,1))\subseteq U$. However, note that $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(0)=x\in U$, so, by continuity, we can find a small interval $0\in I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, such that $\gamma_1(I),\gamma_2(I)\subseteq U$. Then, the compositions $\varphi\gamma_1,\varphi\gamma_2\colon I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ are defined. Since differentiability is a local property, the derivatives $(\varphi\gamma_1)^{\prime}(0),(\varphi\gamma_2)^{\prime}(0)$ do not depend on the chosen interval $I$ and they are all we need to define the tangent space.